# NSURLDownloadDelegate not being called when download is initiated from NSOperation

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoperation

I just switched my app over to use an NSOperationQueue to manage a downloads queue. I am both initiating the NSURLDownloads, and handling all of their delegate callbacks, from within my NSOperation subclass. However, when I just went to test it I found that the none of the delegate methods are being called. I found some stuff online about how this is a known issue with NSURLDownload (what I found said it only posts delegate messages to the main thread), but the NSURLDownload class reference says:

"Note that these delegate methods are called on the thread that started the asynchronous load operation for the associated NSURLDownload object."

This has me thinking that the bug was, at least should've been, fixed in Lion. Yet I'm running 10.7.2, and NSURLDownload is definitely not behaving correctly for me. Is there something I'm missing here? I didn't declare the delegate methods in the header file, but that shouldn't matter... does it?

(I understand that an alternative would be for me to use NSURLConnection. However, I'm really hoping to be able to use the download-progress features of NSURLDownload.)

I have my NSOperation subclass set up to run concurrently: I have overridden start instead of main.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me with this,

Sam

P.S. I'm posting this to the Apple dev forums also, in the hope that more people will see it.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLDownload registers with NSRunLoop to provide its callbacks. Each runloop is tied to a particular thread. In your case, in your NSOperation, you set up the NSURLDownload, which registers with the runloop for whatever thread your operation happens to be running on (which isn't deterministic). However, after you exit from your -start or -main method, the thread (and it's runloop) are likely torn down.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1712/_index.html for a similar issue.